# I can't copy the transform matrix from one layer to another in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I need to copy the scale and translate properties from one item to another in paperjs.

I've tried using

```
itemA.copyAttributes(itemB, false)
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything?

I've also tried

```
itemA.transform(itemB.matrix)
```

Which again doesn't work. I can copy the translate using the lines below

```
itemA.position.x = itemB.position.x
itemA.position.x = itemB.position.x
```

But I can't figure out how to copy the scale, any ideas

Answer (score 1):

One trick to be able to copy transformations from one item to another is to set [item.applyMatrix](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#applymatrix) to `false`.
This will have the effect of storing item translation, scaling and rotation into properties instead of applied them to its geometry.
You will then be able to apply them to another item.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
// Create an orange filled square.
var squareA = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.center - 200,
    to: view.center - 100,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    // Notice that matrix is not applied, this will allow us to copy scaling and rotation later.
    applyMatrix: false
});

// Create a blue stroked square by cloning the orange one.
squareB = squareA.clone();
squareB.strokeColor = 'blue';
squareB.fillColor = null;

// Transform the orange square.
squareA.translate(100, 100);
squareA.scale(2);
squareA.rotate(80);

// Replicate transformations to blue stroked square by copying individual values.
squareB.position = squareA.position;
squareB.scaling = squareA.scaling;
squareB.rotation = squareA.rotation;
```